# Clustered JBoss Messaging, XA-recovery: JMSSecurityException

Tags: jboss, messaging

I'm trying to set up clustered jboss-messaging with XA-recovery on a basic non-clustered, default server config (we *only* want clustered messaging, the rest is stateless with failover only) on JBoss EAP 4.3 (CP04).

When I add XA-recovery I get the following errors in the log:

```
09:05:07,558 ERROR [ExceptionUtil] ConnectionFactoryEndpoint[jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ConnectionFactory] createFailoverConnectionDelegate [s-ar10uuuf-1-k1eztuuf-z44sla-t6avs4]
javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User null is NOT authenticated

[... stacktrace removed for readablity ...]

09:05:07,559 ERROR [MessagingXAResourceWrapper] ********************************Failed to connect to server
javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User null is NOT authenticated
```

Looks like I'm missing some security config - but I cannot figure out where.

I have double and tripple checked my config for errors and I'm using the following docs:

```
http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.3/doc/messaging/JBoss_Messaging_User_Guide/html/recovery.html
```

The same config works like a charm in production config (Update: Not true anymore, see below)

Has anyone done this before? Got any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Update:

The error depends on which datasource I use (DefaultDS vs. MyOwnDS) in the messaging config (*-presistence-service.xml). I have tried the following scenarios:

1. DefaultDS/HSQLDB: Works (of course this is the standard config...but who wants to use this config in production?)
2. DefaultDS/MySQL: Works (this is an acceptable work around)
3. MyOwnDS/MySQL: Does NOT work

It cant be that messaging depends on the datasource being named 'DefaultDS', so I guess there is some configuration associated with DefaultDS that goes missing when I use my own DS. But I cannot figure out what...

There is an entry (HsqlDbRealm) in login-config.xml that uses 'DefaultDS' but it doesn't look like it's used by messaging?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasource used for authentication is specified in messaging-jboss-beans.xml.